# Release Management 'Access Denied' to Read Only files

Tags: ms-release-management

I've been trying to find an answer to this, but nothing seems to be a clear answer.

I have set up Release Management to deploy builds.

The release service account has been added to the administrators group on all destination servers.

The service account can log onto each server and navigate to the deployment       destination.

Deployment Agents have been configured and recycled.

The destination servers are currently loaded with non-release management builds.  We're using team builds and vice versa to copy files to the destination servers.

When I kick off a release management deployment, the process goes right along until it runs into a file that has the read only attribute on it and stops with an access denied.

Given that the release management service account has admin rights to the box, shouldn't it be able to copy the files over?  Do I actually have to remove the read only attributes to the files before it will copy the files over?  The source files have the read only attribute anyway.  Won't that cause yet another problem?

Comment: Can you detail what kind of step are you using when the deployment stops? e.g. PowerShell on Target Machines, Command Line, etc?

Answer (score 0):

The described symptoms remind me of a condition I see sometimes in RM Server deployments where the deployment agent is trying to update a file that is open in a running process (web server/windows service or even windows explorer).

Answer (score 0):

Ideally read-only attribute shouldn't stop it from accessing. Can you please try login using the service account and try copying the same file (marked as read-only) to some other location using normal command prompt on the deployment agent machine?